# Passing instance of a subclass as argument to other subclass

Tags: python, inheritance, arguments, instance, subclass

I am learning inheritance in python using you tube tutorial and I do not understand one concept:
I have made a class employee, subclass developer and manager.

```
class Employee:
def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
self.first = first
self.last = last
self.pay = pay
self.email = first + '.' + last + '@gmail.com'
def fullname(self):
fullname = self.first + ' ' + self.last
return print(fullname)


class Developer(Employee):
def __init__(self,first, last, pay, prog_lang):
super().__init__(first,last,pay)
self.prog_lang = prog_lang


class Manager(Employee):
def __init__(self,first, last, pay, employees=None):
super().__init__(first, last, pay)
if employees is None:
self.employees=[]
else:
self.employees = employees
def add_employee(self, emp):
if emp not in self.employees:
self.employees.append(emp)
def remove_employee(self,emp):
if emp in self.employees:
self.employees.remove(emp)


dev1 = Developer('corey','Schafer',8000,'Python')
mngr1 = Manager('kay','sean',9000,[dev1])
```

Now my confusion is, how are we able to give instance of a subclass as parameter to instance of other subclass? why [dev1] is returning name Corey Schafer? Corey Schafer is the value of fullname() when called....How instance dev1 is picking that up?
Could you please explain me?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, almost sure I don't. Has it to do that you write `return print(fullname)`? This statement prints `fullname` in the constructor of each employee and then returns `None`.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: `return print(fullname)` is almost certainly not what you want; use `return fullname` instead.

Comment: "how are we able to give instance of a subclass as parameter to instance of other subclass" - why would you not be able to do that? In general, objects can be passed as parameters.

Comment: Also unrelated, but you haven't defined what it means for two instances of `Employee` to be equal, so `emp not in self.employees` will always be true, based on the definition of `object.__eq__`.

Answer (score 0):

So when you're calling the constructor for Developer (create a new instance) the `__init__(self,first, last, pay, prog_lang)` function is called implicitly.

If we take a look at the constructor:

```python
def __init__(self,first, last, pay, prog_lang):
    super().__init__(first,last,pay)
    self.prog_lang = prog_lang
```

we can see that the constructor of the super class is called on the second line. This in turn sets the member variables for the instance which are later referred to when the full name is constructed:

```python
def fullname(self):
    fullname = self.first + ' ' + self.last
    return print(fullname)
```

More broadly the language keeps track of which variables are attached to which class and python specifically gives the programmer pretty big freedom when it comes to scope and types. If you wanna read more on this topic i would recommend [W3C's python tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) and more specifically [Type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) and [Inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/)